# How to get the class value from an attribute in lightning controller ?

Tags: lightning, controller, class

I am trying to implement some basic collapse/expand functionalities,for that, i need to read the class value of a div so i used the following code:

```
<ui:button class="button" label="hide" press="{!c.handleCollapseExpand}"/>

  <div class="slds-show" aura:id="CollapseExpand">
     ----- some content -----
  </div>
```

The controller side:

```
    handleCollapseExpand: function(cmp,event,helper){

    var isExapndable = cmp.find("CollapseExpand").get("v.class");
    console.log(isExapndable); // returns undefined --> should print out "slds-show"           
}
```

the console prints out "undefined", do you know how to get the class value in this context ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is [$A.util](https://na35.lightning.force.com/auradocs/reference.app#reference?topic=api:Util) `hasClass` function:

```
var isExpandable = $A.util.hasClass(cmp.find("CollapseExpand"), "slds-show");
```

that you can use to check if a specific class is present.

Answer (score 5):

Use `getElement()` to get the JS element and then you can access it like you would any other JS object:

```
var component = cmp.find("CollapseExpand").getElement();
console.log(component.className);
```

Comment: I will try it right away but do you have an idea why my solution is not working as i prefer always to use native lightning functions over JavaScript functions as recommended by salesforce?

Comment: Your solution isn't working because the `get()` method on components only retrieves the component attributes (aura:attribute) exposed by a component. The HTML attributes on your DOM element aren't exposed that way, so `get()` won't retrieve them so you have to get the DOM element with JS to work with them.